# Q: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL

Tags: linux, ubuntu

The loader gives me this error. I am running Ubuntu 15.04. 
When I do: find /usr -type f -name "libGL*"

I get :

```
/usr/lib/nvidia-352/libGLESv1_CM.so.352.63
/usr/lib/nvidia-352/libGLESv2.so.352.63
/usr/lib/nvidia-352/libGL.so.352.63
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1.3.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLEWmx.so.1.10.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLEW.so.1.10.0
/usr/lib32/nvidia-352/libGL.la
/usr/lib32/nvidia-352/libGLESv1_CM.so.352.63
/usr/lib32/nvidia-352/libGLESv2.so.352.63
/usr/lib32/nvidia-352/libGL.so.352.63
```

So, if i know which is the right one, I can include it by -L"thatfile" 
How can i tell which is the right one ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on whether you want to link a 32 or 64-bit executable you need /usr/lib32/nvidia-352/libGL.so.352.63 or /usr/lib/nvidia-352/libGL.so.352.63. When the linker does not find -lGL, it is looking for libGL.a or libGL.so..

Also, you need to specify only the directory with -L, like `-L/usr/lib/nvidia-352`.

Finally, even though this way you can link, at runtime the library still won't be found, unless you set LD_LIBRARY_PATH before you run the executable, or if you add `-Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/nvidia-352`, too, to the link command (this latter will embed the path into the executable).

Answer (score 0):

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL

@user85392, the installed GL is the run time files only. For compiling and linking, the development files are required : Libraries and headers → →

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev
```

---